# Django Form is not Valid on Model Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm still learning Django. I have a wizard like form workflow where each form is filling out information in succession.

I have a model form that represents what I want inputted from the form:

**Models.py**

```
class AccountParameters(models.Model):
   acctFilterName = models.ForeignKey(AccountFilters)
   excludeClassification = models.ManyToManyField(ClassificationNames)
   tradingCash = models.FloatField()
```

**Forms.py**

This is a dumbed down form and doesn't represent the real implementation. It was for testing.

```
class AccountSelectionForm(forms.ModelForm):

acctFilterName = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=AccountFilters.objects.all().values_list('acctFilterName', flat=True),
                                           label="Account Filters:",
                                            empty_label="Select Here..."
                                            )

excludeClassification = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ClassificationNames.objects.all().values_list('classificationName', flat=True),
                                              label="Classifications Exclusion:"
                                              )

tradingCash = forms.IntegerField(label="Remove accounts whose trading cash < % of AUM")


class Meta:
    model = AccountParameters
    fields =['excludeClassification', 'tradingCash',]
    exclude = ['acctFilterName']
    labels = {
        'acctFilterName': _('Account Filters:')
    }
```

**views.py**

```
def accountSelections(request): # NewRebalnce 2: AccountParameters with Accounts and Trading Form

if request.method == "POST":
    form = AccountSelectionForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        accountParameters = AccountParameters


    #tradingCash = form.cleaned_data['tradingCash']

    return render(request, 'NewRebalance_3.html', {'model_selection_form': ModelSelectionForm()})
else:
    form = AccountSelectionForm()
return render(request, 'NewRebalance2.html', {'account_selections_form': form})
```

I'm not sure that I'm using Modelforms correctly. What I needed was a way to create a select drop down for my acctFilterName so I created the query set manually.

When I save the form it's not valid and in the form cleaned data I get the following:
 Notice that the cleaned data only has the tradingCash field.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this? Why is the Form in valid?

[image: Screenshot of Debug]

Comment: Where in the views.py did you save your form?

Comment: I don't because form.is_valid() is FALSE

Answer (score 1):

try to remove `.values_list('acctFilterName', flat=True)` from the `ModelChoiceField` and remove `.values_list('classificationName', flat=True)` from the `ModelMultipleChoiceField`.

They should be like this:

```
acctFilterName = forms.ModelChoiceField(
queryset=AccountFilters.objects.all(),
label="Account Filters:",
empty_label="Select Here...")

excludeClassification = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
queryset=ClassificationNames.objects.all(),
label="Classifications Exclusion:")
```

---

[.values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) will strip your queryset of all the data the ModelChoiceField needs to recognize the item, leaving only the model fields you specify as an argument. Namely, what you're removing here is the primary key of the model which is fundamental.

Comment: The problem with what you explain is that the objects then don't allow you to select the dropdown by the name. Values_list allows you to select the name. I think something else is missing here that I don't understand.

Comment: You have 2 options to solve this problem. 1: create a "def __unicode__(self):" method on the model you use which returns what you want displayed as the drop down option. 2: pass a to_field_name argument to ModelChoiceField which contains the name of the field you want rendered as the drop down option. Both options are documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield under "to_field_name".

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. "to_field_name" is the primary key of the model, not what gets displayed to the user. What gets displayed to the user is the result of the "def __unicode__" method on your model.

Comment: Here, put this code in your model and let it return what you want displayed as an option to your user: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#unicode

Comment: Thank you for this. However, here is what the docs say: <select id="id_field2" name="field2">
<option value="obj1.name">Object1</option>
<option value="obj2.name">Object2</option>
...
</select> The issue is that the Object 1 displays the String of the object not the Name of it. I must be missing something. I can't imagine that this widget would produce <Accounts Object> on each select text striing.

Comment: if you want Object 1 to be the Name field of your model, the `def __unicode__` function of your model should simply `return self.Name`. What gets displayed in "Object 1" is simply what the unicode function returns. If no unicode function is specified on the model, it simply returns <Accounts Object>. Try it. Add this code to your model AccountFilters in models.py: `def __unicode__(self): return self.Name`

Comment: No. I ended up using the init method and using queryset on the fields. However, I am getting the same behavior where the form is not valid. I'm wondering if that is because I'm making an ajax call after the select widget changes. I get data from the server to do a jquery population of data to a grid. After I submit the form is invalid

Comment: what do you get in form.errors? Does the dropdown display correctly? What do you see in the produced html code of the dropdown as "value" of each select option?

Comment: Saturnix..you are very keen...Here it is: <ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul> I think it has to do with the way the widget is being rendered. self.fields['acctFilterName']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=AccountFilters.objects.all().values_list('acctFilterName', flat=True),
                                     empty_label="Select...",
                                     label="Account Filter Name:")

Comment: obviously. Since you're removing the primary key with .values_list('acctFilterName', flat=True) he won't be able to recognize which model you chose.

1) remove values list
2) define a unicode method on the model AccountFilters

Comment: Saturnix. The unicode did work. I will continue to see if it makes the Form valid but I understand what you are saying. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you redeclaring the fields on your `AccountSelectionForm`  ModelForm???

Better this way:

```
class AccountSelectionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['excludeClassification'].queryset = ClassificationNames.objects.all().values_list('classificationName', flat=True)
        self.fields['acctFilterName'].queryset = AccountFilters.objects.all().values_list('acctFilterName', flat=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AccountParameters
        fields =['excludeClassification', 'tradingCash',]
        exclude = ['acctFilterName']
        labels = {
            'acctFilterName': _('Account Filters:')
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This should be a comment and should not appear as an answer, please post your questions to comment section first.

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment yet :(, not enough reputation.

Comment: So this is my lack of knowledge of how this works. AcctFilter is a look up. I want this queried to the backend as a modelchoice field but could not do so. Notice in the queryset that I populate the values for the widget explicitly.

Comment: Don't need to do that, you can do:

`def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['excludeClassification'].queryset = ClassificationNames.objects.all().values_list('classificationName', flat=True)`